# Rewrite URL with .htaccess for multiple parameters

Tags: .htaccess

This question might be a duplicate. But I did not find any solution worked for me.
I want to rewrite URL, where I have one and two level parameters. first parameter is `p` and second is `sp`

`www.domain.com/home` should point to `www.domain.com/index.php?p=home`
and
`www.domain.com/projects/99` should point to `www.domain.com/index.php?p=projects&sp=99`

How do I do in .htaccess?

Currently My htaccess is as followes,

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\$ index.php?p=$1&sp=$2 [L]
```

The problem with this htaccess is that it correctly points one level url. ie., www.domain.com/home. But not the two level url. ie. www.domain.com/projects/99

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have to treat the rules separately. All Conditions preceding rules only apply to a single, immediately following rule. You tried to 'chain' two rules. The second rule never could have matched, since the first one was a catch-all that changed the syntax. Apart from that you have to make sure that the first rule does not catch unwanted requests. Also think about whether you want to use the `*` or the `+` operator in the patterns. I suggest you use the `+` operator, so that you have a clear error message when empty values are requested for a 'page' or a 'subpage'.

So this might come closer to what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1&sp=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. After the above change, it is working fine. But when I go to a 2nd level URL, my references such as javascript src, css links and img sources are wrong. It looks for these files relative from the 2nd level url. How do I fix this?

Comment: This sounds like a client side problem: most likely you specify relative paths for those resources to load from? The browser only knows about the unmodified request url, so he creates the wrong absolute url when trying to load the resources. So either you have to redirect the browser instead of just server-internally rewriting the request urls (ugly, since visible) or you have to create clean urls for the resources. Typically this is done by defining a clean and sound 'base url' once inside the server side  scripts and use that to build absolute path for the resources to be loaded.

Comment: Ya, it's because of relative path. I have solved it, by specifying full path from root.

Comment: Sure, that is possible, a fast and easy solution. However this makes your application tied to a certain position. Try to use a formal 'base url' or 'installation path' you set at a central place instead. This makes your application portable.

Comment: Thanks arkashca. Is it using `basename(__FILE__)`? Since, all my pages uses index.php, I defined a variable to set base dir and use it everywhere. Is there a better way?

Comment: IF that index.php file is the only controller in your application then yes, that should be fine. The problem most projects face is that automatic detection of such a base is not always possible. That is why many projects/applications allow the manual definition of a base inside their configuration.