# mod_rewrite in Wordpress installation to replace multiple keys/variables

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create mod_rewrite rules to redirect the following url in my wordpress site:

www.mywebsite.com/pg/2/row/20/filter/all/filtercity/foo,bar

to

www.mywebsite.com/detail?pg=2&row=20&filter=all&filtercity=foo,bar

My problem is that wordpress included the following rules in the .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I tried the following RewriteRule and it kind of works if I comment the last RewrireRule from Wordpress.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule . /index.php [L]]
RewriteRule ^pg/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ ?pg=$2 [R]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The above works only for urls like

www.mywebsite.com/pg/2 => www.mywebsite.com?pg=2

A few questions:

1 - how can I configure .htaccess to process the url only when it finds the following keys

/pg and/or /row and/or /filter and/or /filtercity

for all other urls, it should execute the standard Wordpress RewriteRule . /index.php

2 - also the url can have all of the keys or only a few of them. For example:

/pg/2/row/20

/row/20/filter/all

how can I configure the .htaccess to process all the different combinations of keys?

3 - when I tried replacing

```
RewriteRule ^pg/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ ?pg=$2 [R]
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^pg/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ detail?pg=$1 [R]
```

I got a 404 error from the server. Not sure why. Any ideas?

Thank you.

**EDIT 1:**

I tried adding [L] to the end of my RewriteRule (see below)

```
RewriteRule ^pg/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ ?pg=$1 [R,L]
```

and moving the standard Wordpress rewrite rule to the next line

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

After doing that I no longer get server 404 error. However the CSS files stop loading.

Answer (score 0):

> 1 - how can I configure .htaccess to process the url only when it
>   finds the following keys
>
> /pg and/or /row and/or /filter and/or /filtercity

Read this [Rewrite URL with .htaccess for multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786340/rewrite-url-with-htaccess-for-multiple-parameters)

The above answer helps you to solve your problem when have a standard url format.

> 2 - also the url can have all of the keys or only a few of them. For
>   example:
>
> /pg/2/row/20
>
> /row/20/filter/all

You are trying to do something out of URL semantics. When you try to access a resource, the path should be same every time. You can pass pg/0/ if you are on the starting page. But who can stop you from going out of URL semantics? :) In that case you have to have all the combinations as rules in your .htaccess. Follow the above solution, with all URL combinations it will work.

My Suggestions:

- Don't Struggle with .htaccess if you are not familiar and your need is only URL rewrite (it is powerful though)
- Pass everything to the index file and parse in your code, for your case have a look at this page http://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview