# wordpress url rewrite help needed

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a wordpress site and has template page. I am passing class ID as cid parameter. http://www.example.com/class-details/?cid=51

I want it to have like http://www.example.com/class-details/

I wrote rule below in .htaccess 
RewriteRule ^class-details/?([^/]*)$ example.com/class-details/$1 [NC,R,L]

It leads to recursive redirection. I tried checking wordpress redirect API a lot. but no luck. Please guide me for this.

Comment: check this stack Answerer, may it useful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786340/rewrite-url-with-htaccess-for-multiple-parameters

Comment: It's possible but what about the `cid` GET parameter ? Don't you care to remove it ?

Answer (score 0):

Better to create custom post type, then you don't need to pass the cid or anything and you will have Rewrite URL.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<rule enabled="true" match-type="wildcard"> 
    <from casesensitive="true">/class-details/cid=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$</from>
    <to type="passthrough">/class-details?cid=$1</to>
</rule>
```