# mod_rewrite rewrite engine is not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following link and i would like to change it with modrewrite. In my computer i have the newest xampp.

I have the following link: http://localhost/site/index.php?site=blog&action=watch&blogID=1&title=my_new_site

Would like to change to: http://localhost/site/blog/1/my_new_site

Or if you have sollution maybe i will use http://localhost/site/blog/my_new_site

I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?site=$1


RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?site=blog&action=watch&blogID=$1&title=$2
```

EDITED:

I changed my rule but still does not working

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?site=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?site=blog&action=watch&blogID=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Still do es not working the following: http://localhost/site/blog/1/my_new_site

I got the following error: The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rewrite URL with .htaccess for multiple parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786340/rewrite-url-with-htaccess-for-multiple-parameters)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786340/rewrite-url-with-htaccess-for-multiple-parameters

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: .htaccess located is in the "site" folder

Comment: For which URL it is not working now?

Comment: This one: http://localhost/site/blog/1/my_new_site

Comment: Does `/blog/` have another .htaccess?

Comment: nope, If i write to the browser http://localhost/site/blog/1/risk 
It redirected to  http://localhost/index.php?site=blog&action=watch&blogID=blog&title=1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84230/discussion-between-zsolt-janes-and-anubhava).

Comment: Make sure it's enabled in apache2. command: a2enmod rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .htaccess in `/site/`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /site/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?site=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?site=$1&action=watch&blogID=$2&title=$3 [L,QSA]
```