# .htaccess rewrite rule for directory structure

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I was perusing stackoverflow looking for the answers to PHP seo friendly path parameters and came across a couple of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786340/rewrite-url-with-htaccess-for-multiple-parameters) but nothing exactly like I need. Im sure my biggest problem is not fulling understanding `RewriteRule`. Anyway here is what I need:

**1) I need to remove the (.php) from all the pages**

```
http://www.example.com/directory1/file1   <---- no .php
http://www.example.com/directory1/file2   <---- no .php
http://www.example.com/anotherDirectory/file1   <---- no .php
```

**2) pages down some directory be able to grab query parameters in an SEO friendly form.**

```
http://www.example.com/directory1/file2/param1/value1/param2/value2
```

Hopefully with a `$_GET`. Here is the directory structure:

```
/index.php 
/directory1/
      --file1.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3
      --file2.php
/anotherDirectory/
      --file1.php
```

This is what I have (but does not work i.e doesn't get query params)

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)$ index.php/directory1/file1.php?param=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**Side note:** 
1) How do I handle optional params? Like in the case param1-3 might be optional or just param2-3 might be optional
2) Also do I need a different set of rules for each file?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @starkeen how do I write the `RewriteRules` to do the tasks in bold. I also edited the question hopefully it makes a little more sense? :)

Comment: @starkeen is that clearer?