# PHP Urlrewriting Multiple query parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

I have the problem, that I when I enter this into my browser:

```
http://localhost/myString
```

I can get myString by writing `$_GET['id']`.
This works thanks to my following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ /myFile.php?id=$1
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Now I want to add the possibility that users can change the default language. I want this to be possible by entering:

```
http://localhost/en/myString
```

myString should be accessible through `$_GET['id']` and my language code with `$_GET['lang']`.

I am completely new to writing .htaccess configs so this is what I tried but didn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ /chat.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)$/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ /chat.php?id=$2&lang=$1
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Comment: Note that `$` signifies the end of the string to be matched. A basic example might be: `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$`

Comment: If the language is optional, you might try: `RewriteRule ^(?:([a-z]{2})/)?([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$`. Here's an [explanation](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5E%28%3F%3A%28%5Ba-z%5D%7B2%7D%29%2F%29%3F%28%5B0-9a-zA-Z%5D%2B%29%24).

Comment: Also see [Rewrite URL with .htaccess for multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14786531/924299).